# Waiting for two events

Tags: shell-script, synchronization

I have the following requirement: I have a script executing every N hours which downloads a file via wget, and then does some processing (outputing results to several files). Once this is finished, it should do some final calculation comparing the output to the previous instance executed:

```
N0: download, process, compare to previous (in this case none, so exit)
N1: download, process, compare to N0
N2: ...
```

The problem is that the final comparison should be done once both computations are done. I'm trying to figure out what the best way would be but they all seem a bit brittle. Any hint to help me go in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, if your script has done the final calculation and is ready to compare it to the previous result, you could check for the existence of a ".previous" file. If the file exists, then compare the results; if the file does not exist, then create it.

In pseudocode:

```
...
# download
# process
if [ -f somefile.previous ]
then
  compare result to somefile.previous
else
  echo result to somefile.previous
fi
...
```